# test junit for coverage with mock

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, mockito

sorry for my english.
i have a problem with junit tests.
the client asks for coverage for all classes, even for dto / model / entity (even if it's wrong, I have to do it).
but i have trouble testing getters and setters.
I can't cover, I have tested many solutions but either 0 coverage or in error, what can I do?

my class:

```
@Entity
 public class AnagrafeUser {

private String firstName; 
private String lastName; 

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
} }
```

my class test

```
public class AnagrafeUserTest {

@InjectMocks
private AnagrafeUser anagrafeUser;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void setanagrafeUser() throws Exception {
    when(anagrafeUser.getFirstName()).thenReturn("fistname");
    when(anagrafeUser.getLastName()).thenReturn("lastName");

    anagrafeUser.setFirstName("fistname");
    anagrafeUser.setLastName("lastName");
}
```

always error, for example for last when :
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:

1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
   tks

setter not coverage.

NEW test, coverage 100%, but is ok?

public class AnagrafeUserTest {

```
@InjectMocks
private AnagrafeUser anagrafeUser;

Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    anagrafeUser.setFirstName("a");
    anagrafeUser.setLastName("a");
    anagrafeUser.setUserCode("a");
}

Test
public void setanagrafeUser() throws Exception {
    assertNotNull(anagrafeUser.getFirstName());
    assertNotNull(anagrafeUser.getLastName());
    assertNotNull(anagrafeUser.getUserCode());
}
```

}

Comment: Why use mocks at all here? Just `set` a value and assert the `get` return value?

Comment: with a real instance? it is not wrong?

Comment: This is the actual class/ "logic" you're testing, and there are no external dependencies here to be mocked. So no it's not wrong to use it directly without mock.

Comment: interesting, tks.
and also this, is not correct (i have difficult with inject/mock/mockbeans) ?
add in question

Comment: You should be asserting the actual value itself (i.e. assertEquals), rather than just not null. That way, you're truly testing the "behavior" which is that `set` sets the value and `get` returns it without any change.

Comment: tks thanks for the explanation
I have another small question: when using @injectMocks
is given a real instance of AnagrafeUser with its mocked dependencies or a mocked instance of AnagrafeUser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need not to struggle that much. 1st of all this is simple **POJO** class. so you can make use of **Assert** class that provides you assertion methods, useful for writing tests cases.

```
public void AnagrafeUserTest{

AnagrafeUser anagrafeUser = new AnagrafeUser();

@Test
public void setanagrafeUser(){
anagrafeUser.setFirstName("Harry");
anagrafeUser.setLastName("jackson");
Assert.assertEquals("Harry",anagrafeUser.getFirstName());
Assert.assertEquals("jackson",anagrafeUser.getLastName());
}}
```

I would never recommend you to use Mockito here since this this is just basic POJO class. Mockito we use if there is dependency in the code ( like database n all). In that case we use Mockito to create dummy object n perform dependent operations.